# Why didn't Spider-Man's spider-sense detect Ant-Man's attack?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man, marvel, captain-america-civil-war, ant-man

In *Captain America: Civil War*, there was a scene where an ant-sized Ant-Man was on Captain America's shield while it is held by Spider-Man. Ant-Man then grew larger, sucker punched Spider-Man and took Cap's shield. What's weird to me is that Ant-Man was able to sucker punch Spider-Man despite Spider-Man's spider-sense ability.

In a later scene, Spider-Man spider-sensed the object thrown to him by Bucky and was able to evade it and even throw it back, despite being distracted by pursuing and fighting Falcon at that moment. Why did Spider-Man's spider-sense not detect Ant-Man's attack? Does it have something to do with Ant-Man's ability?

Comment: Spider-Man's spider-sense isn't the same as omniscience. He misses stuff, especially when distracted.

Comment: He had just recently received his powers so he may not be fully aware of his spider sense

Comment: @Richard Spider-Man didn't seem to be distracted before Ant-Man's attack. But if he is, he should even be more distracted when he was able to spider-sense Bucky's attack later, as he was pursuing and fighting Falcon at that moment.

Comment: I would think that a spider would be more aware of ants, considering ants are food. Guess not.

Comment: @Ellesedil The same thought crossed my mind. Spiders should be extra aware of ants. =)

Comment: @Ellesedil:   Ants are not a danger to spiders.    Therefore spider-sense not triggered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When Spidey has the shield, he does notice Ant-Man there, but only at the last second, right before he took it from him.

> Hey, guys. Something...

Comment: So it's supposedly a reaction time issue. Interesting...

Comment: @DestinyDarren Well, he hasn't been Spider-Man for very long, he might not know about the spider-sense yet.

Comment: Another option would be that his senses are actually overwhelming him, and he can't differentiate between threats easily. Peter DID mention to Stark that his powers were causing him pain, and that he had to intentionally limit himself.

Comment: Ahh, yes, but he was wearing the mask during that scene, so might've been able to sense Ant-Man there.

Comment: True that. In the end, it just boils down to inexperience lol

Comment: Which is odd, considering that Parker has been Spider-Man for about a year by the time this scene happens.

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure it was just 6 months. And even then, Spidey didn't really have any experience fighting super-powered individuals. Maybe only the common thug.

Comment: According to http://screenrant.com/marvel-spider-man-origin-civil-war/ , he's been Spider-Man for about a year. Also, I agree that he hasn't had any experience fighting superheroes, but Tony did say to stay back and web them up, although in this scene he was in front on the big confrontation. But yes, he has only fought thieves and such until now. So as you said, I guess it's just inexperience and the restriction on his senses.

Comment: Cool, thnx for the link.

Answer (score 19):

In the comics, his spider sense tends to not help as much when he's surrounded by danger or if he's lost in thought. The airport battle is an example of him being surrounded by danger, and he can only focus on one "danger" at a time. So yes, ironically he can get distracted by his spider sense going crazy with "alerts".

IIRC, Ant Man also surprised the heck out of everyone with his attack. So he managed to catch Spidey off guard. In role playing games this is called winning the initiative or a "presence attack" in super hero games.

So Ant Man's attack was so impressive that Spidey was momentarily awestruck and couldn't escape in time. It's not enough to have spider sense; he has to react to it in time.

From the movie, Peter did mention to Stark that he needs the goggles on his old costume to avoid sensory overload from his powers.

UPDATE: I would also like to add one or two points: 
Spidey's agility is great but he's not "un-hittable" (i.e. Falcon finally managed to land a hit) and the way to deal with high agility types like Spidey is to throw "area attacks" at them; which is precisely what Ant Man did at the airport.